# DAX totals does not show correct value in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a Tabular Cube connected to Power BI. I calculate the measures in SSAS tabular usin DAX and the totals in Power BI does not show correct values.

Measures:

**RF M1**

`RF M1:= SUM(_RF M1)`

**RF M1 Err**

`RF M1 Err:= ABS([ACT]-[RF M1])`

**RF M1 MAPE**

`RF M1 MAPE:= CALCULATE(DIVIDE([RF M1 Err];[ACT])*100)`

**RF M1 ACC**

`RF M1 ACC:=
IF([RF M1 Err]=BLANK();BLANK();
IF([RF M1 MAPE]>100;0;100-[RF M1 MAPE])
)`

The dataset isn't complete in the picture, but there are no negativ values so **RF M1 MAPE** and **RF M1 ACC** arent showing correct totals.

[image]

Do you have suggestions on an alternative solution to get the correct total values?

Comment: [RF M1 Err] is ABS([ACT] - [RF M1]) ... that's a bit smaller number than [ACT].  The Ratio in [RF M1 MAPE] falls a bit short of 100%.  The math all looks correct to me.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I follow, but if [RF M1 Err] is a measure, it will sum all [ACT] in the context and then sum all [RF M1] in the context and then subtract the total [RF M1] from the total [Act] and then take the absolute value. Did you want that, or did you want it to subtract row by row and sum the absolute values of those calculations?

Comment: @mmarie I would like to subtract it row by row. Sum by column and not using the formula on the total for Mape and Acc.